# Debug multiple startup projects in WSL from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can Visual Studio be set to debug a solution with multiple startup projects in WSL? With [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2022) I can only figure out how to debug a single project in WSL.

In VS Code there is a [launch-configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) where you can define 'compounds' and then use them to debug multiple projects in an established remote connection to WSL. Is there something similar for Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. @Marlon

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to switch your launch profiles around so that WSL is first in the list, effectively making it the default. Thus, when you start multiple projects, they use the WSL launch profile.